# SQL query with two columns as foreign keys of the same table

Tags: sql

I have two tables

Table A

```
    id ! name ! fk_1_table_B_1 ! fk_2_table_B_2
-------|------|----------------|--------------
    1  | John | 1              | 3
    2  | Paul | 2              | 1
    3  | Anna | 4              | 2
    4  | Alan ! 3              | 1
```

Table B

```
    id | code
-------|------
    1  | EN
    2  | US
    3  | FR
    4  | IT
```

The idea is to obtain the following query

```
    id ! name ! code (fk_1_table_B_1) ! code (fk_1_table_B_2)
-------!------!-----------------------!-----------------
    1  | John | EN                    | FR
    2  | Paul | US                    | EN
    3  | Anna | IT                    | US
    4  | Alan ! FR                    | EN
```

If Table A had only one FK Column from Table B I would do

```
SELECT tableA, name, tableB.code 
FROM tableA, table B
WHERE tableA.fk_1_table_B_1 = tableB.id
```

How can I do this with Table A having two columns as FK from B? What should I select in the SELECT?EN

Thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should join to the same table twice, giving it two different aliases:

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, b1.code, b2.code
FROM tableA a
JOIN tableB b1 ON b1.id = a.fk_1_table_B_1
JOIN tableB b2 ON b2.id = a.fk_2_table_B_2
```

Note how this query uses ANSI join syntax for better clarity: rather than listing all tables in the `FROM` clause, it puts each of the aliased `tableB`s in its own `JOIN` clause.

Comment: It's best to be in the habit of using the full join syntax like this in general.  Even if you don't have to, it helps you to be aware of how the tables link together.

Comment: For this kind of queries you have to use `ON` clause and you cannot write it like  CROSS JOIN without `ON`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
select a.id, a.name,
(select b.code from B b where b.id = a.fk_1_table_B_1),
(select c.code from B c where c.id = a.fk_1_table_B_2),
 from A a
```